# Running apex batch from controller with parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, controller

This is my controller.

```
public class vfcontroller
{
    public Date startdate{get;set;}
    public Date enddate{get;set;}

    public PageReference submit() {

      System.debug('@@@1'+startdate);
      System.debug('@@@2'+enddate);
      batchclass  shn = new batchclass(startdate,enddate); 
        database.executeBatch(shn);

        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Success.'));

           return null;

     }
}
```

This is batch class

```
    global class batchbenchforecastupdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

     Date startdate;
     Date enddate;

    public batchbenchforecastupdate(Date startdate,Date enddate) {


        startdate= startdate;
        enddate = enddate;

        System.debug('###1'+startdate);
       System.debug('###1'+enddate);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'Select id from contact';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope) {

         System.debug('line1'+startdate);
         System.debug('line2'+enddate);        

         }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

i am getting a null pointer exception. in debug line1 and line2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've "shadowed" the class names with parameter names of the same value. In this case, you need to use "this" to refer to the class' variables:

```
public batchbenchforecastupdate(Date startdate,Date enddate) {
    this.startdate = startdate;
    this.enddate = enddate;
    System.debug('###1'+startdate);
    System.debug('###1'+enddate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation that may help here - the variables startdate and enddate are within the scope of the method and you're updating those, rather than those within the class scope. 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271683/why-can-we-use-the-same-name-for-local-variable-in-different-scopes

It's not typically good convention to have variables in different scopes with the same name because of confusions like this that can arise.